# Mongo: Two collections with pagination (in single list in html)

Tags: mongodb, view, pagination

Currently in our system we have two separate collections, of `invites`, and `users`. So we can send an `invite` to someone, and that `invite` will have some information attached to it and is stored in the `invites` collection. If the `user` registers his account information is stored in the `users` collection.

Not every `user` has to have an `invite`, and not every `invite` has to have a `user`. We check if a `user` has an `invite` (or visa versa) on the `email` address, which in those case is stored in both collections.

Originally in our dashboard we have had a user overview, in which there is a page where you can see the current users and paginate between them.

Now we want to have one single page (and single table) in which we can view both the invites and the users and paginate through them.

Lets say our data looks like this:

`invites: [
    { _id: "5af42e75583c25300caf5e5b", email: "john@doe.com", name: "John" },
    { _id: "53fbd269bde85f02007023a1", email: "jane@doe.com", name: "Jane" },
   ...
]`

`users: [
    { _id: "53fe288be081540200733892", email: "john@doe.com", firstName: "John" },
    { _id: "53fd103de08154020073388d", email: "steve@doe.com", firstName: "Steve" },
    ...
]`

Points to note.

- Some users can be matched with an invite based on the email (but that is not required)
- Some invites never register
- The field names are not always exactly the same

Is it possible to make a paginated list of all `emails` and sort on them? So if there is an `email` that starts with an `a` in collection `invites`, that is picked before the `email` that starts with a `b` in collection `users` etc. And then use `offset` / `limit` to `paginate` through it.

Basically, I want to "merge" the two collections in something that would be akin to a MySQL view and be able to query on that as if the entire thing was one collection.

I'm preferably looking for a solution without changing the data structure in the collection (as a projected view or something, that is fine). But parts of the code already rely on the given structure. Which in light of this new requirement might not be the best approach.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UNION" join if that is what you are asking about ( it seems to be ). The better pattern here is to instead put all the data into a **single collection** and just include a "_kind" field or similar to denote the separate items for "invites" and "users". So it's a true structural change and not a "query" change that you are actually looking for here.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but was hoping someone would come up with a brilliant solution either way.

Comment: Well the "brilliant" solution is to actually merge the "two" collections into "one". That really is the only way. MongoDB does have "views", but they're merely aggregation pipelines in disguise and UNION joins are just something they do not do. It's not really a concept that applies to MongoDB anyway. The biggest usage of UNION in "SQL land" is to get common data from two tables which actually have different fields in them. MongoDB being "schemaless" does not have the restriction. Hence put it all in the same collection. Not all solutions are here's a line of code to solve your problem.